# C++ Partially specializing parameter in fuction

Tags: c++, templates

As a way of learning and understanding templates in C++, we have to solve a rather simple problem with templates. Currently my program is structured as followed (minus the unrelated methods):

"LFO.h"

```
enum Behaviors {LIFO, FIFO};

template<typename DataType, Behaviors Behavior, int MaxElems = 10>
class LFO {
public:
    bool Palindrome(LFO& p);
}
```

"StringFIFO.h"

```
template<int MaxElems = 10>
class LFO<std::string, FIFO, MaxElems> {
public:
    bool Palindrome(LFO& p) {
        std::cout << "FIFO Palindrome." << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}
```

"StringLIFO.h"

```
template<int MaxElems = 10>
class LFO<std::string, LIFO, MaxElems> {
public:
    bool Palindrome(LFO& p) {
        std::cout << "LIFO Palindrome." << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is.. When I attempt to access the `Palindrome(LFO&)` function:

```
auto myStringFIFO = new LFO<string, FIFO, 5>();
auto myStringLIFO = new LFO<string, LIFO, 5>();

myStringFIFO->Palindrome(*myStringLIFO);
```

It says that the Palindrome requires a `LFO<std::string, 1, 5>` which is a `FIFO` instead of `LFO<std::string, 0, 5>` which is the `LIFO` that I wish to pass into the method.

When I attempt to call the `Palindrome(LFO&)` method on my `LIFO` instead, the exact opposite happens. Somehow "LFO&" becomes specified according to which specialized class I call it from.

I'm quite stuck on how to fix this. I've attempted adding a template to the method in the base class, which fixes the error in my IDE, but throws an error that no definition for the method is found.

It's pretty hard to explain correctly as I'm not very familiar to templates.

Comment: Your palindrome argument must be an instance of the specialized template, this is your function signature.

Comment: `template<int MaxElems = 10> class LFO<std::string, FIFO, MaxElems>` -- specializations shouldn't have default arguments.  That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @PieterMoens Nowhere on that 1000+ line page do I see a non-primary specialization with default arguments.  But I could have missed it.  Can you be more specific than linking to a 1000+ line page?  A token or tokens I can search on?

Comment: @Yakk My bad. I've been staring at my screen for too long it appears. You said specialization, I was thinking templates in general. Appologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a template specialization (primary or not), the name of the template is short hand for this particular instance of the template.

```
bool Palindrome(LFO& p) {
    std::cout << "LIFO Palindrome." << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

so this `LFO` is this specific `LFO` specialization.

```
template<class T, SubB, int SubE>
bool Palindrome(LFO<T,SubB, SubE>& p) {
    std::cout << "LIFO Palindrome." << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

this is a function that takes a templated type, behavior and max size.

```
template<SubB, int SubE>
bool Palindrome(LFO<std::string,SubB, SubE>& p) {
    std::cout << "LIFO Palindrome." << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

this one doesn't template the type, but does template the behavior and max elements.

Comment: In my search for a possible solution, I have tried this in my "LFO.h" `template<Behaviors pBehavior>
    bool Palindrome(LFO<std::string, pBehavior, MaxElems>& p);`  and the same in both the "StringLIFO.h" and "StringFIFO.h" but when accessing now with `myStringFIFO->Palindrome<LIFO>(*myStringLIFO);` it throws an 'undefined reference to method'

Comment: @pieter implement it?  And you don't have to pass the template argument manually, deduction works.

Comment: I found my error lies in the basic structure of my specialized classes and my method was never even reached. I am fixing that now and will edit the question with a solution shortly. Your answer is correct and has been marked as such. Thank you.